# How to look for users friends near a location in facebook API

Tags: facebook

It there a way to query Facebook API for users connection near a location ( long/lat) , I was not able to find in their documentation any way to achieve that.

Answer (score 1):

No there is no api from facebook where you can find users connection near by.

But you can get your friends location by using friends_location permission and users location by using users_location.

Once you get users location you can try to find the friends location nearby by using google or yahoo apis.

User location (i.e current_location) is returned in form of (id,state,city,country) which you can use to generate the lat/lng.

You can use this FQL to get more location info :   http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/place/

or you can use yahoo or google apis.

Answer (score 1):

Facebook doesn't keeps track of your location down to latitude and longitude.  That would require knowledge of physical ip addressing schemes of..the world.  If you can find a database that has cities listed in lat/long then you can approximate who is closest.  If their full address is listed in their personal information then you may be able to cross reference with Google Maps or some other service for more accurate information.  I'm not sure how the check-in service works with Facebook and if that holds lat/long information though, so that would be something to look into.